# Getting a shortcut on the start screen from installer in Windows 8.1 (NSIS)

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I'm guessing this answer exists somewhere but I've been searching and trying things for 8+ hours now so I'm asking.

How do I get an icon on the Windows 8.1 (and 8, and 7) start screen at installation time?

I'm using [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). I've tried both version 2.46 and 3.0b0 (not that I thought that had anything to do with it but might as well try both).

What I think is the relevant part of my script is this

```
!define APPNAME "MyApp"
!define COMPANYNAME "Greggman"

SetShellVarContext current
CreateDirectory "$STARTMENU\Programs\${COMPANYNAME}"
CreateShortCut "$STARTMENU\Programs\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\myapp.exe" "$\"$INSTDIR\somedir\somescript.foo$\" --app-mode" "$INSTDIR\logo.ico"
CreateShortCut "$STARTMENU\Programs\${COMPANYNAME\${APPNAME}-Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"        createDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}"
```

It creates a shortcut but it's only visible on the all apps screen (or whatever that's called)

[image: apps screen]

There's nothing on the start screen

[image]

Maybe that's the way it should be but it's hard for me to believe the average user is going to know they either have to search for the app they just installed or else they have to click that tiny arrow in the bottom left of the start screen and then find the "greggman" section among all those tiny icons, then then click MyApp to run the thing they just installed.

I've also tried both HKLM with admin rights and HKCR with only user rights. I'd prefer to stick to HKCR but since it didn't work in either case I don't think that's the issue.

Where do I put shortcuts or registry settings or whatever to add a tile to the start screen. Or is there some other thing I should do so my users can find MyApp after they've installed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 will pin your shortcuts to the Start Screen, (ALL of your shortcuts if the flag discussed above isn't set - on a per-shortcut basis).  On Windows 8.1, only the USER can pin shortcuts, and they have to do it manually.  The change was made because users complained their Start Screens were getting too cluttered.

Comment: Hmm. I can see the point but I'm guessing many users will have trouble running my app after installing as they won't be able to find it. Oh well, I guess I can't do anything about that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry but it's a Microsoft enforced rule.  On Windows 8, installing older software that wasn't Start Screen aware would pin EVERYTHING, including the utility shortcuts such as "help", "settings", "uninstall", etc that didn't belong on the Start Screen.  In a bit to please users, Microsoft changed the way it works with Windows 8.1 and made it so that NOTHING can be automatically pinned and requires the user do it themselves.  Here is a little discussion from MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Windows is supposed to pin it for you. This pinning can be controlled by  [System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`CreateShortcut "$SMPrograms\MyApp.lnk" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"` should be enough. You are not really supposed to create links to the uninstaller/readme/help files in the start menu and if after removing those you are left with a single shortcut then you should not create a subfolder either. I'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

Comment: I tried that and I got no links whatsoever. Even searching didn't find the app. I tried this `CreateShortCut "$STARTMENU\Programs\${APPNAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" "$\"$INSTDIR\somedir\somescript.foo$\" --app-mode" "$INSTDIR\logo.ico"` and [the location of the icon moved](http://imgur.com/v7A3wQe) but it still doesn't show up on the start screen. :(

Comment: It worked for me but I tested on Win 8.0. It is possible that it will only work on a fresh install, maybe Windows knows what it has auto pinned?

Comment: [How to Add Shortcuts to the Start Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is what my example does. [Desktop App Tiles on the Start Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj673981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption needs to be set to **avoid ending up on the start screen**. And finally, [this thread](http://tinyurl.com/nryn4ws) speaks about a ResetCache value that can be used to reset the start screen.