# How to pin shortcut to start menu with NSIS?

Tags: windows, nsis

I've got an NSIS installer script which calls `CreateShortcut` to add an entry to the start menu.   However, I would like to set the option to "Pin to Start Menu" in that newly created shortcut.

Is this possible?   I've seen some [VBScript examples](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-pin-items-to-Start-ee960ad8) on how to do this.. is that my only option with NSIS, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 should pin it automatically for you [while 8.1 will not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054159/getting-a-shortcut-on-the-start-screen-from-installer-in-windows-8-1-nsis).

While it is possible to simulate pinning a shortcut you are [not really supposed to do it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx).

If you want to be evil and not follow the guidelines you can use [this plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StdUtils_plug-in)...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the [`InvokeShellVerb`](http://muldersoft.com/docs/stdutils_readme.html#d452a779) function of the [`StdUtils`](https://github.com/lordmulder/stdutils) plugin.

This works for Windows 7 and up.

Here's an **example** preserved here for posterity...

```
!include 'StdUtils.nsh'

RequestExecutionLevel user ;no elevation needed for this test
ShowInstDetails show

Section
    IfFileExists "$SYSDIR\mspaint.exe" +3
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP 'File does not exist:$\n"$SYSDIR\mspaint.exe"$\n$\nExample cannot run!'
    Quit
SectionEnd

Section
    DetailPrint "Going to pin MSPaint..."
    ${StdUtils.InvokeShellVerb} $0 "$SYSDIR" "mspaint.exe" ${StdUtils.Const.ShellVerb.PinToTaskbar}
    DetailPrint "Result: $0"

    StrCmp "$0" "ok" 0 +3
    MessageBox MB_TOPMOST "Paint should have been pinned to Taskbar now!"
    Goto +2
    MessageBox MB_TOPMOST "Failed to pin, see log for details!"
SectionEnd

Section
    DetailPrint "Going to un-pin MSPaint..."
    ${StdUtils.InvokeShellVerb} $0 "$SYSDIR" "mspaint.exe" ${StdUtils.Const.ShellVerb.UnpinFromTaskbar}
    DetailPrint "Result: $0"

    StrCmp "$0" "ok" 0 +3
    MessageBox MB_TOPMOST "Paint should have been un-pinned from Taskbar now!"
    Goto +2
    MessageBox MB_TOPMOST "Failed to un-pin, see log for details!"
SectionEnd
```